# Pandas read_clipboard broken in pandas 0.12?

Tags: python, pandas

Since I updated pandas from version 0.11 to 0.12, read_clipboard doesn't seem to work anymore:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6dead334eb54> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_clipboard()

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboard.py in read_clipboard(**kwargs)
     16     from pandas.io.parsers import read_table
     17     text = clipboard_get()
---> 18     return read_table(StringIO(text), **kwargs)
     19 
     20 

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

What I did was:

- Open a csv file in Excel 2010
- Copy a range of cells, including headers
- Perform read_clipboard in iPython Qt console as described in above code block

After downgrading to 0.11, this procedure worked fine again. I'm using pandas for python 3.3 Win7 32 bit.

Is this a bug in pandas? Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: changes in 0.12 clipboard API used [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/a7d069dc2dbf451e5286cfca3497fa03c77dc900#pandas/util/clipboard.py) could explain the issue

Comment: Ok, I added an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4561) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug in the string presented to py3; I'll fix it in master, but you can do this local edit.

in `C:\python33\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboard.py`

after `text = clipboard_get()`

add `text = text.decode('UTF-8')`

apparently the clipboard routine gives you back bytes (and not a string) in py3

Comment: Which is most likely a Windows/Python issue, not `pandas`. Although we could be nice and call `compat.bytes_to_str` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution, and seems to be related to ctypes.
you can find more information here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13946

One workaround could be to replace the calling to

```
text = clipboard_get()
```

in

```
C:\python33\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboard.py
```

with the following:

```
    from tkinter import Tk
    r = Tk()
    text = r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
```

[Here is an image with the Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EXPT.png)