# Encode error with df.to_clipboard()

Tags: pandas

is there a way to use to_clipboard() when the dataframe contains special caracters

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID' : ['é', 'bar'] * 10})
df.to_clipboard()
```

In this cave i have an error : 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 14:

How can i solve that ?

thanks

Windows 8.1
Python 3.4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203915/pandas-read-clipboard-broken-in-pandas-0-12

Comment: if you are using >= 0.15., ``df.to_clipboard(encoding=....)`` is supported (export using utf-8/latin1 might work).

Comment: doesn't seems to work with 0.15.1:


to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: @steboc: You might get that error if the particular encoding raises an exception. What encoding did you specify?

Comment: i tried almost everything 'cp1522' , 'latin1' ,'utf-8' ....

Comment: I have the same error. Did you find a solution? even pandas 0.16 has this error.