# Python 2.7 Anaconda Pandas error(Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pandas

I'm doing a data science course on udemy using python 2.7, running Anaconda. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm getting the following error running with the pandas module:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flyveren/PycharmProjects/Udemy/15_DataFrames.py", line 13, in <module>
    nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()
  File "/home/flyveren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard.py", line 51, in read_clipboard
    return read_table(StringIO(text), **kwargs)
  File "/home/flyveren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 474, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/flyveren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 260, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/home/flyveren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 721, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/flyveren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1170, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 769, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7544)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 791, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:7784)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 844, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8401)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 831, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8275)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1742, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:20691)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 5, saw 12`

I've tried `conda uninstall pandas` and subsequently `conda install pandas` again to see, however with the same result. The package is there, it tells me an error if I uninstall and try to run the code again with missing package, but it gives this error when it's properly installed.

Anyone knows what's up?

Comment: The error points to error parsing clipboard data, you have to post your raw input data you are trying to load, also post your pandas and numpy version

Comment: The tutor in the video uses iPython in a browser, and he copies to the clipboard from a webpage while I am running it natively in PyCharm IDE. Maybe that's why? Pandas is `0.15.2` and Numpy is `1.9.2`. Thanks.

Comment: The IDE shouldn't make a difference, you'll need to edit your question with the URL in question and the data that you're trying to copy to the clipboard.

Comment: Sorry not related to the question but can you share the course link? I am searching for the same!?

Comment: I think it's a known bug in pandas [as seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203915/pandas-read-clipboard-broken-in-pandas-0-12)

Comment: @geeksoul It's the [learn python for data analysis course](https://www.udemy.com/learning-python-for-data-analysis-and-visualization)

Comment: `read_clipboard` does work can you post the url, I'm not going to watch a video trying to find the specific point that you are referring to

Comment: @EdChum [here is the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFL_win-loss_records), however, the course only copies the first 5 columns to the clipboard. I am unsure of how to do so when I run it in PyCharm and it apparently doesn't copy well from clipboard? Would appreciate your help with this :)

Comment: Well I just selected the first 5 rows, pressed `ctrl+c` and then entered `pd.read_clipboard()` and it worked fine for me. I'm running pandas 0.16.1 numpy 1.9.2 python 3.3.4 64-bit

Comment: @EdChum I'm using Anaconda as he does and run in that environment, although it's Python 2.7? I'm not sure why it doesn't work. My code is as below: `import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()
print nfl_frame`

Comment: Try upgrading to latest pandas and numpy and try again

Comment: @EdChum I did do the latest installations and did run `conda update` on both `pandas` and `numpy`. So should be up to date? `pandas                    0.16.2` and `numpy                     1.9.2` are installed according to anaconda

Comment: Well it's not if your versions are not 0.16.1 and 1.9.2

Comment: @EdChum anaconda provides the info that `numpy                     1.9.2` and `pandas                    0.16.2` so it should be up to date I think

Comment: your pandas version is not 0.16.1 so it's not the latest, besides you can copy and paste from your clipboard into a new text file and load it using `read_table`

Comment: @EdChum pardon my ignorance but wouldn't `pandas 0.16.2` be the latest version rather than `pandas 0.16.1`? How would I install the 0.16.1 rather than the 0.16.2 which according to conda is the latest, then?

Comment: Sorry yes 0.16.2 is the latest version, but the fact remains you should be able to copy and paste that table into a blank text file and load it, but besides that it works fine for me pasting from the clipboard buffer

Comment: It might be an Ubuntu issue then, I'm not sure. It pastes into gedit just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution was essentially to create a virtual environment and install the needed packages independently. Some issues with dependencies on my system, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I watch same lecture at udemy and face same problem.

I change my browser from internet explorer to chrome. (I'm using windows7 & VS2013 with PTVS)

Then, error does not occur.

However, delimeter has some problem.
Space should not be used as delimeter according to lecture, however, it does.
So, result is not perfect.