# nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard() Panda system crash

Tags: python, pandas, windows-10

I am running windows 10, python 3, every time i run this command 
nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard(), the whole system crash

Comment: I don't think it has much to do with the question you think it's a duplicate of. Granted, the problem is that the question is lacking all the basic info, but I think I have the same problem as the OP.

This happens when I run read_clipboard in a jupyter notebook only (works fine in ipython in cmd.exe, and on python 3.5 only. Pandas doesn't give back an error message like the linked question, but just "stops working" resulting in a dead kernel

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with Python 3. I tried it on python 2 and luckily it works. Also I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203915/pandas-read-clipboard-broken-in-pandas-0-12). Supposedly it's a bug.